# Как установить value в input из сервера и изменять его?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

У меня такая проблема, есть такой инпут

```
              <TextField
                id="outlined-read-only-input"
                label="Display Name"
                variant="outlined"
                value={nameValue !== "" ? nameValue : name || ""}
                onChange={(e) => setNameValue(e.target.value)}
                onBlur={() => setName({ variables: { name: nameValue } })} 
              />
```

**name** - это значение которое приходит из сервера, оно должно сразу отображаться в инпуте

**nameValue** - это новое значение которое я ввожу в инпут

Когда я начинаю удалять значение из инпута и остается в нем 1 символ, значение возвращается к предыдущему . как пофиксить это?

Я понимаю что проблема здесь `value={nameValue !== "" ? nameValue : name || ""}` . но как можно избежать ее?

Comment: По идее, нужно добавлять проверки на touched/pristine, или что там в react есть у полей)

Comment: Там вроде есть свойство `defaultValue`

Comment: @vp_arth да, но если я в дефолВелью кидаю значение из сервака, он пустой

Comment: @vp_arth ну и ошибка еще в консоле ForwardRef(InputBase) contains an input of type text with both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element and remove one of these props.

Comment: [Асинхронная загрузка defaults](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-driscoll-mod05?file=/src/App.js), вдруг поможет